# Environment based Branching Strategy and good practice for GIT

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I have been seeing feature based branching strategy where I see master and dev for long running.

I am looking at a scenario where you have dev -> UAT -> master. Not all commit in dev will eventually pushed to UAT branch and not all commit in UAT will go into master (i.e. if UAT fails then it does not go into production). Is something like that possible or good practice?

Another question, should all development in dev branch be commits that is 99% completed fix? (i.e. all tested in remote/local branch before merging into dev) I have problem over my end as we have developers committing multiple commit with 1-2 liner fix with to test their codes. This makes the git history extremely confusing.

Answer (score 0):

> I have problem over my end as we have developers committing multiple commit with 1-2 liner fix with to test their codes.

This is typically done on feature branches which are then merge as no-ff (no fast-forward) in order to squash their internal history into one commit one dev.

Dev can be an integration branch where you merge those feature branches: if one of those features won't make it to prod, you simply [revert the merge commit representing that feature](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html). [git flow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html) works a bit like that.